# Android: how to rotate image from one point to other point?

Tags: rotation

I want to rotate and move an image from one point to another point like in the card games. I am new in android and want to move cards similarly that u can see in this image .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9T1p.png

Comment: Simplest way would be simply add a rotation to the view (to rotate from start rotation to final rotation) and also add animated movement.  Could be +- desired effect. (If it is not easy to add two transformations to the same view, You could position card as a subview on some invisible container view and - move container, while  rotating the card. I hope You get the Idea I am presenting. Not the best way, but simplest. Just in case. Good luck!